# Transferring default user picture field to new user picture field

Tags: users

Drupal 7.

I have a site where users can upload a picture of themselves (default Drupal field: user picture.) This field is used in different views.

I would like to use the *User Picture Field* module and use the field provided by the module instead of the default Drupal user picture field.

Switching fields in the views is a simple operation and it works well with newly uploaded pictures. However, with pictures uploaded before the installation of the module, the pictures displayed are no longer the users' pictures but the default "no photo" image.

Is there a way to have the (older) photos of the default user picture field transferred to (or at least displayed by) the new field?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to do it at the database level. Copy the old field contents into the new field.

Comment: I guess it is done be referring to the file id (fid) and you could try to replace those 1:1